# Reference request: tensor products of states separate the points of tensor product of $C^*$-alagebras 

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras

Suppose  $A\otimes B$ is the minimal tensor product of  two unital $C^*$ algebras $A$ and $B$.
We know that the set of states, $\{\phi\otimes\psi|\phi\in S(A),\psi\in S(B) \}$ on  $A\otimes B$ separates the points of $A\otimes B$. Here $S(A)$ and $S(B)$ are the state spaces of $A$ and $B$ respectively.
 My question is:

is there any reference for us to cite this result?

Comment: Thanks. It seems that this result (tensor states separate points) is well-known for experts, but I could not find it in any textbook or papers. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$ be faithful rep's of $A$ and $B$. Then $\pi=:\pi_A\otimes\pi_B$ is a faithful rep of $A\otimes_{min} B$ (see Thm 4.9(iii) in Chapter 4 in M. Takesaki, Theory of Operator algebras I, Springer-Verlag, 1979). For $x$ a non-zero element in $A\otimes_{min} B$, use then a vector state associated with some elementary tensor $\xi_A\otimes\xi_B$ to separate $\pi(x)$ from $0$.